# How to enable highcharts x and y axis scrollbars?

Tags: highcharts

How can I enable highcharts scroll bars. Most of the forums suggests to use Highstock to get the scrollbar. I saw highstock demo at http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo. It does not support all the chart types that highcharts supports.

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: After doing some R&D found a solution, for the div that requires scrolling I set overflow to scroll and in the load event setting the width appropriate for screen display. Then scroll bars are coming automatically.  Below is the sample.chart: {
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                    load: function (event) {
                         $('#container).width(800);
                    }
                }
            },

Answer (score 0):

After doing some R&D found a solution, for the div that requires scrolling I set overflow to scroll and in the load event setting the width appropriate for screen display. Then scroll bars are coming automatically. Below is the sample.

chart: { type: 'column', events: { load: function (event) { $('#container).width(800); } } },