# Horizontal Scrollbar for highcharts, NOT Highstock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, scrollbar

I want to implement the scrollbar in highcharts, not highstock because it will cost additional money for my company (just for a scrollbar, does not make sense). I have tried this but apparently does not help me:

[How to enable highcharts x and y axis scrollbars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985425/how-to-enable-highcharts-x-and-y-axis-scrollbars) .

There are some examples here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/3076/
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/224-scrollbars-for-any-axis/

but with highstock, I want to do the same thing with Highchart.

From what I have found out Highcharts does not support scrollbars. If I just insert use `overflow: scroll` on a wrapped div of the chart, that would still make my title center in the middle of a long div and also the y axis will be hidden when I go to the right of that long div.

Is there any way to have ScrollBar with the above things on a highchart (NOT HIGHSTOCK) ?

Here is my option

```
let options = {
  legend: {
    itemStyle: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: '13px'
    },
    // width: 780,
    itemWidth: 130,
    floating: false
  },
  xAxis: {
    position: {align: 'left'},
    text: null,
    }, // ,
    // tickLength: 0
    type: 'category',
    categories: categories,
    min: 0// ,
    // max: 10
  },
  navigator: {
    enabled: false
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true,
    showFull: false,
    barBackgroundColor: 'rgb(44,89,142)',
    barBorderRadius: 0,
    barBorderWidth: 0,
    buttonBackgroundColor: 'rgb(44,89,142)',
    buttonBorderWidth: 0,
    buttonArrowColor: 'white'
  },
  yAxis: {
    // minorTickInterval: 'auto',
    title: {
      /* style: {
        textTransform: 'uppercase'
      }*/
    }, // ,
    min: 0,
    // max: 20,
  },
  // General
  background: '#FFFFFF',
  chart: {
    height: 500,
    width: 3900,
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, Helvetica, 
sans-serif'
    },
    borderColor: '#ACB2BC',
    borderWidth: 1,
    events: { load: function fn() { console.log(this); /* this.width(800); 
*/ } } // #container
  },

  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    candlestick: {
      lineColor: '#404048'
    },
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: -50,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white'
        }
      },
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      data: values,
      showInLegend: true
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'reports',
    data: values
  }],
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  }
};
```

I am using React. I just pass the options to a Highcharts.

```
 this.chart = new Highcharts['Chart'](
  this.refs.chart,
  this.props.options);
```

Comment: I did it with an outside wrapper div , the only problem with that is that if i scroll on the right the y axis disappears as it goes to the left. I want the y axis to stay fix as i scroll to the right

Comment: I have written custom code for adding scrollbar without  highstock library once, maybe it will help you with your chart: http://jsfiddle.net/LnneuLoy/11/

Comment: Thanks, but your code does not have a scrollbar. I accessed the link and it does not show any scrollbar

Comment: Yes, you need to zoom first to see scrollbar

Answer (score 4):

`chart.scrollablePlotArea`

Since Highcharts v7.1.2, a [scrollable plot area](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.scrollablePlotArea) can be defined for either horizontal or vertical scrolling, depending on whether the minWidth or minHeight option is set. This does **NOT** require Highcharts Stock (aka Highstock) to be used.

A demo from the API reference is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/scrollable-plotarea) and below:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 700,
            scrollPositionX: 1
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Scrollable plot area'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Open on mobile and scroll sideways'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        tickWidth: 1,
        title: {
            text: 'Wind speed (m/s)'
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        opposite: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' m/s',
        split: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            lineWidth: 4,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidth: 5
                }
            },
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            pointInterval: 3600000, // one hour
            pointStart: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 31, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Hestavollane',
        data: [0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1, 1.3, 1.5, 2.9, 1.9, 2.6, 1.6, 3, 4, 3.6,
            5.5, 6.2, 5.5, 4.5, 4, 3.1, 2.7, 4, 2.7, 2.3, 2.3, 4.1, 7.7, 7.1,
            5.6, 6.1, 5.8, 8.6, 7.2, 9, 10.9, 11.5, 11.6, 11.1, 12, 12.3, 10.7,
            9.4, 9.8, 9.6, 9.8, 9.5, 8.5, 7.4, 7.6]

    }, {
        name: 'Vik',
        data: [0, 0, 0.6, 0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.2,
            0, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.3, 0, 0.1, 0.2,
            0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 3.1, 3.1, 2.5, 1.5, 1.9, 2.1, 1, 2.3, 1.9, 1.2,
            0.7, 1.3, 0.4, 0.3]
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Using this method - is there a way to listen to the scrolling event? I tried in crazy ways but nothing worked. I've tried catching the bubbling scroll event and searched for "highcharts-scrolling" class named element but couldn't get a listener on the scrolling.

Comment: Yes, you could add an event listener to the scrolled element via Highcharts API - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b72axzyw/).